# Buffer polyline to kilometres in custom projection in QGIS, Python, R

Tags: qgis, python, r, polygon, buffer

I have a map containing polyline squiggles all over the world (shown below). I need to buffer these lines by 50 km either side, resulting in polygons.

[image: Figure 1. Global polyline squiggles that need to be buffered by 50 km]

I have reprojected my data to this custom projection:

```
+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

However, when I buffer my polylines using the Vector>Geoprocessing>Buffer option QGIS reverts to WSG84 with an error bar stating that my crs is unknown.

There are two options I am considering:
**(1)** i) Use ESPG 3857 instead, as suggested as [option 4. here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106988/create-buffer-in-meters) (although a commenter in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet) (top comment of the top answer) states that EPSG 3857 is not in real 'm' - so I am now unsure if this option is valid). ii) Reproject to my custom crs.

**(2)** Try to force the buffer to work in my projection using code in R or Python.

**So my questions are:**
**a)** Is (1) a valid method?
If so, despite the 'metre units not being real metres' comment, then I am down to use the easier method, followed by reprojecting to my custom crs.
**b)** Or if are there some code options (2) that allow me to use my own crs, I would love to hear those too!

Comment: Unless QGIS has a buffer function/tool that supports geodesic distances, there's not a good projected CRS for worldwide data like this. 3857 has horrible distance distortion away from the equator, and cea (cylindrical equal area) also has bad distance distortion.

Comment: One solution would be to buffer individual lines or portions of lines by projecting each into a customized ProjCRS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you're after here is a **geodesic buffer**. I suspect the problem is that your CRS is a custom one (assigned a code > 100000) so it's not in GDAL/OGR's database of known CRSes.

I just noticed that **mmqgis** plugin allows buffers in km and nautical miles ... if you install this, use **mmqgis > create > create buffers**

[image]

Here are 50 km buffers around country borders from the Natural Earth 110m dataset...

[image]

I'm not sure what algorithm it uses - It's been a while since I looked at the source :) So I'm not sure if it's using true geodesics or projection.

You can use the **measure tool** to check if the results are accurate enough for your needs.