# Buffering geometry with points in WGS84 using shapely?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapely, wgs84

I have a polygon in python shapely that I would like to buffer with a 100 foot buffer.

If the polygon is stored as a series of WGS84 lon/lat points how would I go about calculating the distance of the 100ft buffer?

I can't find anything searching google and seek guidance on the algorithm.

Comment: I think this answer gives the direction: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/107009/46073. If you want pure python, try pyproj: https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I will assume that your points are in [WGS84 = EPSG: 4326](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/). Convert the lon/lat points to UTM meters using `pyproj` lib. First we need to get the correct projection. The issue is that to convert to [UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) you need to know your UTM zone. That is something you can look up separately; UTM zone will depend on the longitude of the initial shape.

```
import pyproj
import shapely.geometry as shpgeo

proj = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=???, ellps="WGS84", datum="WGS84")
```

I used a standard helper function to convert Polygons and MultiPolygons to and from UTM. The arguments are a shapely Polygon or MultiPolygon object and a PyProj Proj object.

```
def toFromUTM(shp, proj, inv=False):
    geoInterface = shp.__geo_interface__
    
    shpType = geoInterface['type']
    coords = geoInterface['coordinates']
    if shpType == 'Polygon':
        newCoord = [[proj(*point, inverse=inv) for point in linring] for linring in coords]
    elif shpType == 'MultiPolygon':
        newCoord = [[[proj(*point, inverse=inv) for point in linring] for linring in poly] for poly in coords]
        
    return shpgeo.shape({'type': shpType, 'coordinates': tuple(newCoord)})
```

Using this function, you can convert your shape (`initial_polygon`) to UTM, buffer it in meters (100 feet is 30.48 meters), then convert back to lon/lat if you so desire

```
init_shape_utm = toFromUTM(initial_polygon, proj)
buffer_shape_utm = init_shape_utm.buffer(30.48)
buffer_shape_lonlat = toFromUTM(buffer_shape_utm, proj, inv=True)
```

The output will be a shapely Polygon (or MultiPolygon) buffered to 100 feet, with coordinates in the WGS84 lon/lat system.

Comment: This is such a life-saver. Created the gist here for quick reference for Indian UTM zone: https://gist.github.com/harshithjv/bcd3fef5661ce0a2ec20224e8e4ac415

Simplified the code with `transform_wkt_with_buffer` function that can be called with just two parameters, after configuring appropriate params to to `proj` object.