# How to come up with Radius maps in qgis

Tags: qgis

I am relatively new to qgis. I have GPS coordinates of two types of sites in csv format, (water point site and sanitation site). **I wanted to find out if it is possible to create a 100 meter radius on all the water point sites to find out how many of the sanitation sites are outside the 100 meters.**

Comment: You need to create a buffer. Look at buffer tool in QGIS. To avoid problems in case your CRS is not in meter, check this question. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106988/create-buffer-in-meters

Comment: You could also use a 'Select by Location' (in the Vector -> Research Tools menu) to select all sanitation sites that are within 100 meters of a water point site. That way you don't even need to create a buffer.