# Problem creating buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, buffer

Trying to create a 5km circular buffer around a point. Comes out oval. If I change shp crs it dissappears, if I change basemap crs it stretches it. Something to do with CRS and I know its simple but can't work it out!

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Craig! Perhaps this post might help: [Understanding QGIS buffer tool units?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23856/understanding-qgis-buffer-tool-units)

Comment: Thanks Joseph, but is the oval shape related to units?  I can change the crs of the shp and make it circular (and seemingly the right size), but only if the basemap is distorted... sorry if this is really basic!

Comment: which CRS are you using?

Comment: wgs 84/pseudo mercator

Comment: It is possible that your 5km buffer was correctly created, according to your layer CRS (WGS84/pseudo mercator). Next thing you can check is your project CRS (`Project | Project Properties | CRS`). Please set it to WGS84/Pseudo Mercator and see what happens.